# week number of a date between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need to get the week number between 2 dates, considering the week ends on Sunday ( may not be 7 days )
for clarification assume the dates are  (01-Apr-2014, 31-May-2014)
so the date ( 03-Apr-2014) should be in the first week
and the date ( 06-Apr-2014) will be the first day of the second week and so on.
thanks on advance

Comment: What's the problem you're having with your code? Oh wait, you don't have any! This is not a coding service. Try something and if you have an unexpected result, then ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(@SoughtDate) - YEARWEEK('2014-04-01') + 1
```